# .NET assembly loading

Tags: .net, appdomain, .net-assembly

Does ASP.NET load all dependency assemblies (located at BIN folder) to default appdomain while loading some assembly? Or it will be loaded "on demand" (when CLR need some type from dependency assembly)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know are dependancies loaded on demand (The first time a `Type` of said assembly is used)

The book `CLR via C#` from Jeffrey Richter also explains it in greater detail.

Also, check [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163655.aspx)  which basically talks about the reduction of loaded assemblys (Also answering your question to some point I guess)

Extract from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967164/how-are-dlls-loaded-by-the-clr) question.

> When the CLR just-in-time (JIT) compiles the Start method it needs to
>   load all assemblies referenced within that method. (..)

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. That's what I want to hear)