# In .NET are referenced DLLs loaded on demand at run-time?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are DLLs loaded by the CLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967164/how-are-dlls-loaded-by-the-clr)

In .NET are referenced DLLs loaded on demand at run-time? Or are they all loaded in the beginning. I ask because when running my project with Visual Studio attached, I notice that it is loading symbols for every DLL referenced at the start.

Is this only because I am running in debug with VS attached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check yourself using Procmon (Process Monitor) while running without VS attached. Off the top of my head, I recall they are loaded on demand when the JIT compiler first meets a type. In fact, I work with a mixed solution (managed and unmanaged assemblies) and when an unmanaged dll is missing, the error appears when a type from that assembly is first needed; I even got the call stack for that when running on VS. But I never checked outside VS. As for the theory behind, there's a long explanation in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967164/how-are-dlls-loaded-by-the-clr).