# Project Initialization Takes more time

Tags: c#, winforms, memory-management

When project starts to load it take more time and also `cpu` usage is high. Actually my project is `winform` based one and i used c# language. In that i've referenced 4  external `dll` files and also i'm using `Properties.Settings` to retrieve some last used values for `textbox` and `combobox` tool values. From so much research in `google` i came to know that by linking external dll files it consumes more time and `cpu` usage too. But i need to use those 4 `dll` files otherwise i cant perform my operation. Is that anything i can do to reduce time taking for project load and `cpu` usage ? Can anyone help me in this ?

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: Have you considered to use a profiler? It should help you to find your performance problem by pointing out the functions/methods that takes the longest. Use the redgate profiler (I can't think of others right now) and even if you don't consider buying it, use the evaluation at least.

Answer (score 0):

As @dandrejvv has pointed out, you should first find out what is causing the performance issue.
This can be done using a profiler, or by pausing the execution while the CPU usage peeks, and checking which function is now executing (statistically you will get the time consuming function).

Once you know what is taking time, you can handle it in a background thread.
If it is indeed the dll references you can:

- If you are loading them manually, just do it in another thread.
- If they are referenced in your project, make sure that the first reference to the dll is being done in another thread. This might help as referenced dll's are being [loaded on demand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059047/in-net-are-referenced-dlls-loaded-on-demand-at-run-time)