# Can I use pythonnet without .AddReference?

Tags: python, clr, python.net

The usual way to integrate pythonnet in your project is the following:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('My.Assembly')
import My.Assembly

My.Assembly.DoSomething()
```

What if I don't want the assembly namespace to be imported and be available globally.
Is there any way to achieve something like this:

```
my_assembly = magic_loader('My.Assembly.dll')
my_assembly.DoSomething()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this might be relevant to your case: [How are DLLs loaded by the CLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967164/how-are-dlls-loaded-by-the-clr)

So you could do:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
public class Utilities {
  public static Object LoadCustomCls(string file) {
    Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom(file) ;
    return a.CreateInstance("namespace.someclass") ;
  }
}
```

And calling `LoadCustomCls(file).DoSomething()` might work.

Notice that there is a deeper question here. Are we talking about a security boundary or a code boundary? Why do you need to force this restriction?

Because I am not sure anything you would do , would be a security boundary, as long as you run in the same process. And about the general availability of the assembly, I don't understand why does it matter.

PS. noticed just now that you want python. I am sure it is possible to do the equivalent in python  / to call this C# code directly (ie through the clr.AddReference ).